# Echo golang - issue with Swagger example values

Tags: go, swagger, echo, go-echo

I have ECHO server on GO and assigned on it Swagger.
If I'm using the structure which is on the same package (file) then example values are working well, ex:

```
type Test struct {
    TestField string `json:"test_field" example:"testfield"`

type MaintenanceConfigPage struct {
    ConfigFile  string      `json:"config_file" example:"configfile"`
    Test        TestField   `json:"test"`
}

// maintenance godoc
// @Accept json
// @Produce json
// @Param data body MaintenanceConfigPage true "Config configuration"
// @Success 200 {object} string
// @Failure 400 {object} string
// @Router /maintenance [post]
func maintenanceSetupPost(echo_context echo.Context) error {
    return echo_context.JSON(http.StatusOK, "test")
}
```

So, that on Swagger example value I'm getting correct value:

> {   "config_file": "configfile",   "test": {
> "test_field": "testfield"   } }

But issue is coming when I'm trying to import the struct from another package, like:

```
type MaintenanceConfigPage struct {
    ConfigFile  string                      `json:"config_file" example:"configfile"`
    Test        anotherPackage.TestField    `json:"test"`
}
```

The everything is working, but swagger on example value providing just a

> {}

If someone also receive before such problems and found the solution, please share